# Error while compiling on closure-compiler

Tags: jquery, google-closure-compiler

I want take shorten my JS, but Errors appear while compiling.

Error warning from points like :

```
default = {
        Home:'',
        Max: 5,
}
```

or

```
items: {
     visible: 1,
     width: 200
      }
```

Waring Msg :

```
JSC_TRAILING_COMMA: Parse error. IE8 (and below) will parse trailing commas in array and object literals incorrectly. If you are targeting newer versions of JS, set the appropriate language_in option. at line 162 character 0
visible: 1,

JSC_TRAILING_COMMA: Parse error. IE8 (and below) will parse trailing commas in array and object literals incorrectly. If you are targeting newer versions of JS, set the appropriate language_in option. at line 249 character 0
Home:'',
```

Say me how to solve this error.

Comment: maybe, just maybe, getting rid of the trailing commas mentioned in the warnings will make the warnings go away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
default = {
    Home:'',
    Max: 5,
```

}

needs to be

```
default = {
    Home:'',
    Max: 5
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your options are:

1. turn down the `ES3` diagnostic group to warning or off
2. change the language mode to `ECMASCRIPT5` or `ECMASCRIPT5_STRICT`. EcmaScript 5 standardized trailing comma behavior but IE8 and below will produce syntax errors if you try to run the code uncompiled
3. correct the code to remove the trailing commas.